# prevent css animation restart from extreme start & end points when recalled

Tags: css, animation

Is possible to do make an animation that does not restart quickly from its start & end points when recalled?

For example:
I have an animation that moves vertically a div from `top:0px` to `top:100px` (down),
and another animation that moves vertically this div from `top:100px` to `top:0px` (up),
each animation is controlled by a different button, A and B.
If I press these buttons repetitively, and the div is actually at mid-route
it does not restart from this actual mid-point,
but returns quickly to the extreme start or end point!

see: http://jsfiddle.net/4FB6k/

Is there a way to make the div restarts from the actual point in where it is arrived, when I recall the other animation?

Comment: @bjb568 can you make a little example please?

Comment: This tutorial can help you to learn what you want [Controlling css animation](http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bjb568 comented, the answer is to do it with transitions instead of animations

CSS

```
#a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    transition: top 2s linear;
    top: 0px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b").mousedown(function(){
        $("#a").css({"top":"200px"});
     });
    $("#b").mouseup(function(){
        $("#a").css({"top":"0px"});
     });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4FB6k/1/)